# Raspberrypi as a network monitor without installing pfsense

Tags: networking, rrdtool

Is there a way i can get bandwidth graphs like the one shown below on the rpi2 without having to install pfsense OS on it because i would like to use it for other things. I am thinking i have to monitor the network interface with traffic and save the data,them graph it using rrdtool

[image: RRDTOOL]

Comment: I've closed this because it depends on which OS you do want to use, and  presuming it is Raspbian or some other GNU/Linux variant, the place to ask is our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).  There are probably various solutions to this.

Comment: stop being silly.its a raspberrypi questions and its in the right forum

Comment: It's a relatively obscure question; less than 1% of users will really be interested in doing this.  I promise, no one has written a pi oriented tool for this -- **they've written a linux based tool for this**.  Probably multiples of them.  As a matter of fact, I can almost guarantee that whatever produced that graph will also run on linux.  It was not "the OS", it was some application.  So why don't *you* stop acting like a brat, pull your head out of your ___ and go find out what it is.  In the appropriate place.  Ask pfsense...

Comment: ...Or, since it's BSD based, **ask on U&L** (the "U" includes BSD, and there are pfsense questions there).  I am not going to help you do things the WRONG WAY.  You want help solving a problem.  I am giving it to you by pointing in the right direction.  If you use your brain for an hour or so, you could have this figured out.  If instead you want to argue with people who know what they are talking about, you are going to waste a lot of time and get no where.

Comment: Just to show you what a nice guy I really am, here's a bigger clue WRT "i have to monitor the network interface with traffic and save the data" -- drop dead easy.   Parse and log `/proc/net/dev`.  It's documented; `man proc`.  RTFM as they say.

Answer (score 2):

You can try **ntop**. It shows graphs, network statistics and few other useful things on webpage (default port is `3000`).